# android gitkit custom UIManager - how to use the system's UI in showPasswordAccountLinking

Tags: android, google-identity-toolkit

I'm implementing my own UIManager in the login gitkit process of android app.
Even so, I want the system only to handle the UIManager callbacks:

```
public void showPasswordAccountLinking(String s, IdProvider idProvider);
public void showIdpAccountLinking(String s, IdProvider idProvider, IdProvider idProvider1);
```

How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This version of UIManager does not support overriding a single screen. If you do not want to use the default UIManager, you need to provide your own UI for all the five screens. A new Android SDK is being developed, but there is no ETA yet.

Comment: Is there any new info about mythical new SDK?